# WKWebview pass custom header in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, wkwebview

I am working on WKWebView for loading some web pages. I need to pass some header inside WKWebView for change of language. I have passed successfully, however on server side, its showing other language. Please let me know whether the mechanism of passing is right or wrong.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler{

    NSLog(@"%@",navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [navigationAction.request mutableCopy];
    [request setValue:@"sv" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:
1) You define the header fields too late (after the webview has already started to use the request to load the page)
2) You set the header on a mutable copy of the actual request (so not on the one that's used). This copy is then just dealloced once the method finishes.

Try this here in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
// ... start as you did
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@""]; // I assume you're using a correct URL in your actual code?
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:nsurl];
[request setValue:@"sv" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest]; // I just prefer to add to the view hierarchy before I do anything with it, personal preference.
```

You do not need to do anything regarding the header fields in your `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:` delegate method.

Comment: This only works for the first request. Whenever your webview makes another request, these custom header values are gone.

Comment: You mean when the webview creates requests to load resources? Yes, obviously these headers are gone then, since it creates new requests for this, based on what the webpage says. It would not make sense in the general case to mess with those headers, as they depend on the site's own logic.

Comment: I think there are some valid cases where people might want to add custom headers to a request. They would like to let the server know the request is coming from native for example by adding something like X-IS-MOBILE.

Comment: Yes, that may be the case, but for this it would be best to have a separate delegate method that allows you to modify requests. If I see this correctly, `WKNavigationDelegate` unfortunately doesn't offer that atm. Simply copying any headers from the initial request would be a bad design, though, since that would be a special case (all requests are to be prepared with equal headers). I'm afraid to achieve this now you would have to either inject javascript or use a custom `URLProtocol` or something to intercept outgoing requests. Subclassing might also be an option, but I don"t know that.